# Mixing entities with <br/> tag causes XML parser exception

Tags: java, xml, exception, sax, xerces

I use Java and the Apache Xerces XML parser. The error occurs inside `org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse`.

```
<content id="xxx">&amp;<br /></content>
```

If a line like this appears in an XML document I'd like to parse, the parser crashes and returns the following error message:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

I could narrow the source of the problem down to the appearance of `<br />`, as it works well if I omit it but fail to understand what causes the breakage. The ampersand is correctly escaped and should not in any way interfere with the occurrence of `<br />` as a HTML line separator.

Comment: < and > also special characters for XML. If you have control on source XML, I would suggest using CDATA.

Comment: Any documentation I've seen says that all tags must be terminated, as this is not HTML. It's XML. This is why people should start following XHTML conventions. It's important that the <br /> be terminated I think.

Comment: How can this problem be reproduced? `<content id="xxx">&amp;<br /></content>` is well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it under `!CDATA` like this. This will make it not parsed by the XML parser if that's what you are after. You can read more about CDATA section [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect).

`<content id="xxx">&amp;<![CDATA[<br />]]/>`

Answer (score 0):

You should put text between tags in CDATA:

```
<content id="xxx"><![CDATA[&amp; <br />]]></content>
```

OR write it in this way:

```
<content id="xxx">&amp; &lt;br /&gt;</content>
```